# Is it possible to create a event listener in SQLAlchemy that can create parent record?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

There are two tables: parent and child. I would like to create a event listener ("trigger") that can create parent if child has no parent.

This is what I tried to do:

```
class parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = db.relationship("child", backref="parent",
                               cascade="all, delete-orphan",
                               passive_deletes=True)


class child(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                          db.ForeignKey('parent.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
                          nullable=False)


def create_parent(mapper, connection, target):
    if not(target.parent):
         target.parent = parent()

event.listen(child, 'before_insert', create_parent)
```

Test:

```
c = child()
db.session.add(c)
db.session.commit()
```

and got following warnings and error:

```
C:\Python27\x\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py:79: SAWarning: Usage of the 'related attribute set' operation is not currently supported within the execution stage of the flush process. Results may not be consistent.  Consider using alternative event listeners or connection-level operations instead.
  sess._flush_warning("related attribute set")

C:\Python27\x\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py:37: SAWarning: Usage of the 'collection append' operation is not currently supported within the execution stage of the flush process. Results may not be consistent.  Consider using alternative event listeners or connection-level operations instead.
  sess._flush_warning("collection append")

sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) null value in column "parent_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null).
 'INSERT INTO child (parent_id) VALUES (%(parent_id)s) RETURNING child.id' {'parent_id': None}
```

I found in documentation that this can not be achieved with before_insert event but with before_flush, but I have no clue how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime I found the way to solve this issue.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session as SessionBase

def before_flush(session, flush_context, instances):
    children = [c for c in session.new if isinstance(c, child)]
    for c in children:
        if not (c.parent):
            c.parent = parent()

event.listen(SessionBase, "before_flush", before_flush)
```

If someone find that is not proper way to handle this scenario I will appreciate your comments.