# SAWarning: Usage of the 'Session.add()' operation is not currently supported within the execution stage

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do some operations after an insert occurs on a particular table.

```
user = ModelFactory.create_user(username, email, password)
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

So I have created a method which invokes automatically on  `after_insert`.

```
def notify_user(user):
    print user.id
    book = Book(author=user.id, name='foo')
    db.session.add(book)
    db.session.commit(book)

@event.listens_for(User, 'after_insert')
def receive_after_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    print target
    notify_user(target)
```

But this code shows a warning like,

```
SAWarning: Usage of the 'Session.add()' operation is not currently supported within the execution stage of the flush process. Results may not be consistent.  Consider using alternative event listeners or connection-level operations instead.
  % method)

/home/avinash/.virtualenvs/s2s/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py:68: SAWarning: An exception has occurred during handling of a previous exception.  The previous exception is:
 <class 'sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError'> This transaction is closed
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21355859/3297613) post shows that we have to do the work in the `before_flush`. I tried moving the logic inside before_flush method but it shows that the user.id is None. Yes, that's expected since the entity won't get committed to db.

Likewise I have tried `after_flush` event but still I get the same warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`after_flush` event does work:

```
@event.listens_for(User, "after_insert")
def receive_after_insert(mapper, connection, user):
    print(user.id)
    @event.listens_for(Session, "after_flush", once=True)
    def receive_after_flush(session, context):
        session.add(Book(author=user.id, name="foo"))
```

But why wouldn't you want to make `User.author` a relationship instead?

Comment: At the start of notify user method, I added db.session.flush(), it works

Comment: @AvinashRaj I feel like you're not using the ORM to the fullest potential. A major feature of the ORM is to be able to figure out the order to insert objects in such that it's able to fill in foreign keys.

Comment: You mean `db.session` as `Session` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj They should both work, though `db.session` might be more correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think the accepted solution has a memory leak. According to the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/event.html#sqlalchemy.event.listens_for) for the `event.listens_for` function:

> The once argument does not imply automatic de-registration of the listener function after it has been invoked a first time; a listener entry will remain associated with the target object. Associating an arbitrarily high number of listeners without explicitly removing them will cause memory to grow unbounded even if once=True is specified.

I did some testing, and sure enough, every time the `receive_after_insert` event fired in this scenario, it added a new event to the `event.registry`. I fixed this issue but adding an `event.remove` call to the `receive_after_insert` function like this:

```
@event.listens_for(User, "after_insert")
def receive_after_insert(mapper, connection, user):
    print(user.id)
    @event.listens_for(Session, "after_flush", once=True)
    def receive_after_flush(session, context):
        session.add(Book(author=user.id, name="foo"))
    event.remove(Session, "after_flush", receive_after_flush)
```

Comment: This appears to de-register the event immediately before it has a chance to even be called